# How can I found the circles on image avoiding the internal circles?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, optimization

## How can I found the circles on image using the method minEnclosingCircle but avoid the internal circles?

I'm using the opencv with c++ to detect circles on a image. I was using the method HoughCircles but sometimes it lost some circles or it detected false circles.

Therefore I'm replacing it for the minEnclosingCircle. Now the algorithm is finding all circles, but in some cases it found circles inside other circles and I want avoid this.

The image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxZ43.png) is a example of input and the image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2k6V.png) is it output.

[image]
[image]

The code used to process those images is this:

Start of code:

---

```c++
vector < Circle > houghCircles(Mat thresholdImage, float minRadius, float maxRadiuss) {

  vector < vector < Point > > contours;
  vector < Vec4i > hierarchy;

  findContours(thresholdImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

  vector < vector < Point > > contours_poly(contours.size());
  vector < Circle > circlesTMP(contours.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {

    Point2f detectedCenter;
    float detectedRadius;

    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
    minEnclosingCircle((Mat) contours_poly[i], detectedCenter, detectedRadius);

    if (minRadius != 0 && detectedRadius < minRadius) {
      continue;
    }
    if (maxRadiuss != 0 && detectedRadius > maxRadiuss) {
      continue;
    }

    sf::Circle _circle(detectedCenter, detectedRadius);
    circlesTMP.push_back(_circle);
  }

  vector < Circle > circles;
  for (int i = 0; i < circlesTMP.size(); i++) {
    sf::Circle _circle = circlesTMP[i];
    if (_circle.getRadius() > 0) {
      circles.push_back(circlesTMP[i]);
    }
  }

  cout << "Circles found: " << circles.size() << endl;
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(thresholdImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
  for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
    sf::Circle _circle = circles[i];
    Scalar color = Scalar(200, 187, 255);
    circle(drawing, _circle.getCenter(), (int) _circle.getRadius(), color, 2, 8, 0);
  }

  imshow(drawing, "OpenCVUtil");
  waitkey();

  return circles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link out and change your mode parameter and test your code:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours

check out the results you obtain for CV_RETR_EXTERNAL instead of CV_RETR_TREE as the mode.

Comment: I've already tested that. When I changed that parameter the vector returned by "findContours" is empty.

Comment: then device your own plan .First Compare the centers of the circles with other centers(distance between centers). use a certain threshold to ensure that 2 centers are not too close to each other. If they are then choose the circle with the greater radius among the 2 circles and ignore the other while printing output.